# Android ExoPlayer onProgressChanged

Tags: android, listener, exoplayer, progress, android-media3

How can I monitor progress changes on `ExoPlayer`?
I tried to implement a hidden `MediaController` and overriding `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` methods, but for now without success. I'm wondering if there is another way to listen to the `ExoPlayer` progress.

Answer (score 39):

I know this question is very old. But, I landed on this while implementing `ExoPlayer`. This is to help the others who do the same later on:)

So, I have followed the following methods to track progress of the playback. This is the way it is done in the `ExoPlayer` Google Docs. It works as needed.

Checkout `PlayerControlView.java` in [Google ExoPlayer repository](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

`updateProgressBar()` is the function to update the `SeekBar` progress:

```
private void updateProgressBar() {
    long duration = player == null ? 0 : player.getDuration();
    long position = player == null ? 0 : player.getCurrentPosition();
    if (!dragging) {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(progressBarValue(position));
    }
    long bufferedPosition = player == null ? 0 : player.getBufferedPosition();
    mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(progressBarValue(bufferedPosition));
    // Remove scheduled updates.
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateProgressAction);
    // Schedule an update if necessary.
    int playbackState = player == null ? Player.STATE_IDLE : player.getPlaybackState();
    if (playbackState != Player.STATE_IDLE && playbackState != Player.STATE_ENDED) {
        long delayMs;
        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
            delayMs = 1000 - (position % 1000);
            if (delayMs < 200) {
                delayMs += 1000;
            }
        } else {
            delayMs = 1000;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(updateProgressAction, delayMs);
    }
}

private final Runnable updateProgressAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateProgressBar();
    }
};
```

We call `updateProgressBar()` within `updateProgressAction` repeatedly until the playback stops.
The function is called the first time whenever there is a state change. We use `removeCallbacks(Runnable runnable)` so that there is always one `updateProgressAction` to care about.

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
  updateProgressBar();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which actually means you are polling the state

Comment: @Thomas which actually seems to be a kind of a right solution, because exoplayer itself generates progress events too frequently for UI.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal I have custom progress bar how can i update progress while playing video plz help

Comment: Well, as of today, with exoplayer version 2.14.0 , the above method has changed a lot, finding it hard to get the equivalent methods/variables for dragging, progressBarValue,...

Answer (score 21):

Just try this, its working for me :

```
handler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           progressbar.setProgress((int) ((exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition()*100)/exoPlayer.getDuration()));
           handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
      }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

Here,

- `getCurrentPosition()` : return The current playback position in milliseconds.
- `getDuration()`: The duration of the track in millisecond.

Comment: it works..but it is not resetting to zero after playing a audio

Answer (score 14):

I've found a pretty elegant solution using RxJava. This involves a polling pattern as well, but we make sure to use an interval to poll every 1 second.

```
public Observable<Long> playbackProgressObservable = 
                            Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

The logic here is we create an Observable that will emit a sequential number every second. We then use the `map` operator to transform the number into the current playback position.

```
public Observable<Long> playbackProgressObservable = 
                        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                  .map( { exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() } );
```

To finally hooked this together, just call subscribe, ad the progress updates will be emitted every second:

```
playbackProgressObservable.subscribe( { progress -> // Update logic here } )
```

Note: `Observable.interval` runs on a default `Scheduler` of `Schedulers.computation()`. Therefore, you'll probably need to add an `observeOn()` operator to make sure the results are sent to the right thread.

```
playbackProgressObservable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())        
    .subscribe(progress -> {}) // Update logic here
```

The above statement will give you a **Disposable** which must be disposed when you are done observing.
You can do something like this ->

```
private var playbackDisposable: Disposable? = null

       playbackDisposable = playbackProgressObservable
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThead())        
        .subscribe(progress -> {}) // Update logic here
```

then to dispose the resource ->

```
playbackDisposable?.dispose()
```

Comment: This might not work in the new Exo player update. Player accessed on wrong thread warning might come

Answer (score 7):

Well, I did this through kotlin flow..

```
private fun audioProgress(exoPlayer: ExoPlayer) = flow {
        while (true) {
            emit(((exoPlayer.currentPosition.toFloat().div(exoPlayer.duration.toFloat()).times(100)).toInt()))
            delay(1000)
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
```

then collect the progress like this...

```
val audioProgressJob = launch {
            audioProgress(exoPlayer).collect {
                MP_progress_bar.progress = it
            }
        }
```

Comment: `exoPlayer.currentPosition` can only be accessed from Main Thread, otherwise it throws exception.

Comment: it throws warning not exception.. try this out.. it works perfectly..

Comment: I did try and it throws exception at runtime. I prob. use newest version

Comment: brother, can u comment down the error stack trace ?

Comment: Exception is documented on this page: https://exoplayer.dev/troubleshooting.html#what-do-player-is-accessed-on-the-wrong-thread-warnings-mean

Comment: If you change it to use `flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)`, this approach works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it is the best way, but I achieved this by overloading the `TrackRenderer`.

I'm using `videoPlayer.getBufferedPercentage()`, but you might be able to compute the percentage yourself as well, by just using `TrackRenderer`'s `getBufferedPositionUs()` and `getDurationUs()`

```
public interface ProgressListener {
    public void onProgressChange(long progress);
}

public class CustomVideoRenderer extends  MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer {

    long progress = 0;
    private final CopyOnWriteArraySet<ProgressListener> progressListeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet();

    // [...]
    // Skipped constructors
    // [...]

    public void doSomeWork(long positionUs, long elapsedRealtimeUs) throws ExoPlaybackException {
        super.doSomeWork(positionUs, elapsedRealtimeUs);

        long tmpProgress = videoPlayer.getBufferedPercentage();

        if (tmpProgress != this.progress) {
            this.progress = tmpProgress;

            for (ProgressListener progressListener : this.progressListeners) {
                progressListener.onProgressChange(progress);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addProgressListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        this.progressListeners.add(listener);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear,there isn't a build in EventListener for the progress event, but you can call Handler.postDelayed inside you updateProgress() function to get the current progress

```
 private void updateProgress(){

    //get current progress 
    long position = player == null ? 0 : player.getCurrentPosition();
    //updateProgress() will be called repeatedly, you can check 
    //player state to end it
    handler.postDelayed(updateProgressAction,1000)

}

 private final Runnable updateProgressAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {        
      updateProgress();
    }
};
```

for more details, see the source of [PlaybackControlView.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java#L645) inside Exoplayer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the right approach, but I used [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)  and `TimerTask` to update the progress of the audio being played. 
In my MusicController class I put:

```
private void sendElapsedDuration() {
    //To send the current elapsed time
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(
                            new ProgressNotification(
                                    player.getCurrentPosition(), player.getDuration())
                    );
                    if (player.getCurrentPosition() >= player.getDuration() ){
                        // The audio is ended, we pause the playback,
                        // and reset the position
                        player.seekTo(0);
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                        this.cancel();
                        // stopping the Runnable to avoid memory leak
                        mainHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    }
                }
            },0,1000);
        }
    };
    if(player != null) {
        if (player.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_ENDED)
            mainHandler.postDelayed(r, 500);
        else {
            //We put the TimerTask to sleep when audio is not playing
            t.cancel();
        }
    }

}
```

Then I called the method inside the `onPlayerStateChanged` when adding the listener to my SimpleExoPlayer instance. The code above, sends the elapsed and total duration of the audio being played every 1 second (1000 ms) via the EventBus. Then inside the activity hosting the SeekBar:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void updateProgress(ProgressNotification pn) {
        seekBar.setMax((int) pn.duration);
        seekBar.setProgress((int) pn.currentPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and i found the solution on this [link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3980)

But **solution:**

**1.** create a class like this:

```
   public class ProgressTracker implements Runnable {

        public interface PositionListener{
            public void progress(long position);
        }
    
        private final Player player;
        private final Handler handler;
        private PositionListener positionListener;
    
        public ProgressTracker(Player player, PositionListener positionListener) {
            this.player = player;
            this.positionListener = positionListener;
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(this);
        }
    
        public void run() {
            long position = player.getCurrentPosition();
            positionListener.progress(position);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    
        public void purgeHandler() {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }
```

**2.** and finally use it in your code:

```
tracker = new ProgressTracker(player, new ProgressTracker.PositionListener() {
        @Override
        public void progress(long position) {
            Log.i(TAG, "VideoViewActivity/progress: position=" + position);
        }
    });
```

**3.** in the last step dont forget call purgeHandler when you want release player **(important)**

```
tracker.purgeHandler();
player.release();
player = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Flow extensions (can be used also with the new Media3 API)**:

- *Remaining time:*

```
fun Player.remainingTimeFlow(
    updateFrequency: Duration = 1.seconds,
) = flow {
    while (true) {
        if (isPlaying) emit(abs(duration - currentPosition).toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        delay(updateFrequency)
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
```

- Current position:

```
fun Player.currentPositionFlow(
    updateFrequency: Duration = 1.seconds,
) = flow {
    while (true) {
        if (isPlaying) emit(currentPosition.toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        delay(updateFrequency)
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
```

etc.

Improved solution based on the original [@abhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65598940/3796931) answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this, just listen to `onPositionDiscontinuity()`. It will give you information if the `seekbar` is being scrub

Answer (score 0):

Extend your current player class (SimpleExoPlayer for ex.) and add

```
public interface PlayerEventsListener {
        void onSeek(int from, int to);
        void onProgressUpdate(long progress);
}

private PlayerEventsListener mListener;
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mProgressUpdater;
private boolean isUpdatingProgress = false;

public SomePlayersConstructor(Activity activity, /*...*/) {
    //...
    mListener = (PlayerEventsListener) activity;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mProgressUpdater = new ProgressUpdater();
}

// Here u gain access to seek events
@Override
public void seekTo(long positionMs) {
    mListener.onSeek(-1, (int)positionMs/1000);
    super.seekTo(positionMs);
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int windowIndex, long positionMs) {
    mListener.onSeek((int)getCurrentPosition()/1000, (int)positionMs/1000);
    super.seekTo(windowIndex, positionMs);
}

// Here u gain access to progress
public void startProgressUpdater() {

    if (!isUpdatingProgress) {
        mProgressUpdater.run();
        isUpdatingProgress = true;
    }
}

private class ProgressUpdater implements Runnable {

    private static final int TIME_UPDATE_MS = 500;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListener.onProgressUpdate(getCurrentPosition());
        mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressUpdater, TIME_UPDATE_MS);
    }
}
```

Then inside player activity just implement interface and start updates with `player.startProgressUpdater();`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the player view or the player control view fully or partially(for just the buttons or something) you could set progress listener directly from it:

```
PlayerControlView playerControlView = miniPlayerCardView.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
ProgressBar audioProgressBar = miniPlayerCardView.findViewById(R.id.audioProgressBar);

playerControlView.setProgressUpdateListener((position, bufferedPosition) -> {
            int progressBarPosition = (int) ((position*100)/player.getDuration());
            int bufferedProgressBarPosition = (int) ((bufferedPosition*100)/player.getDuration());
            audioProgressBar.setProgress(progressBarPosition);
            audioProgressBar.setSecondaryProgress(bufferedProgressBarPosition);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

rx java implementation :

```
private val disposablesVideoControlsDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun showVideoControlsAndSimilarTray() {
    videoSeekBar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) seekVideoProgress(progress)
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

    })
    val disposable = Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            calculateVideoProgress()
        }
    disposablesVideoControlsDisposable.add(disposable)
}

private fun calculateVideoProgress() {
    val currentMill = exoPlayer.currentPosition
    val totalMillis = exoPlayer.duration
    if (totalMillis > 0L) {
        val remainMillis = (totalMillis - currentMill).toFloat() / 1000
        val remainMins = (remainMillis / 60).toInt()
        val remainSecs = (remainMillis % 60).toInt()
        videoProgressText.setText("$remainMins:${String.format("%02d", remainSecs)}")
        seekBarProgress.set((currentMill.toFloat() / totalMillis * 100).toInt())
    }
    
}

private fun seekVideoProgress(progress: Int) {
    val seekMillis = exoPlayer.duration.toFloat() * progress / 100
    exoPlayer.seekTo(seekMillis.toLong())
}
```

And finally when you are done :

```
   fun disposeVideoControlsObservable() {
    disposablesVideoControlsDisposable.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on media3 PlayerControlView logic.
Here is the function for identifying and updating the current position, and the entire code can be found in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/whitipet/058e7901aeadff4a1a982c102329018b).

```kt
private fun updatePosition(player: Player? = this.player) {
    handlerUpdatePosition.removeCallbacks(runnableUpdatePosition)
    if (player == null) return

    val position = player.currentPosition
    playerPositionListener?.onPlayerPositionChanged(position)
    val playbackState = player.playbackState
    if (player.isPlaying)
        handlerUpdatePosition.postDelayed(
            runnableUpdatePosition,
            player.playbackParameters.speed.let { playbackSpeed ->
                if (playbackSpeed > 0) ((1000 - position % 1000) / playbackSpeed).toLong()
                else MAX_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS
            }.coerceIn(MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS, MAX_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)
        )
    else if (playbackState != Player.STATE_ENDED && playbackState != Player.STATE_IDLE)
        handlerUpdatePosition.postDelayed(runnableUpdatePosition, MAX_UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Only use onTouchListener with the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

```
    SeekBar exo_progress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);
    exo_progress.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        //put your code here!!
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

This works at least with Exoplayer 2.

There is four playback states: STATE_IDLE, STATE_BUFFERING, STATE_READY and STATE_ENDED.

Checking playback state is easy to do. There is at least two solution: if-statement or switch-statement.

Whatever playback state is going on you can execute your method or set something else for example progressbar.

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
        showControls();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playback ended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buffering..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: may you provide better description about your solution?

Comment: I did hope that helps.

Comment: this doesn't answer any of the question

Answer (score -2):

it's simple

```
var player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
player.addListener(object:Player.Listener{
     override fun onEvents(player: Player, events: Player.Events) {
        super.onEvents(player, events)
                if (events.containsAny(
                Player.EVENT_IS_LOADING_CHANGED,
                Player.EVENT_PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED,
                Player.EVENT_PLAY_WHEN_READY_CHANGED,
                Player.EVENT_IS_PLAYING_CHANGED
              )) {
                   log(msg="progres ${player.currentPosition}") 
               }
     }

})
```

and you can view com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView.java   at 1356 line

Comment: This has nothing to do with changing progress.

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer